# How to write separate log file in syslog server in java using log4j

Tags: java, log4j, rsyslog

I have a web application.I want to write log file of this web application in remote machine using Syslog Appender in log4j.The log file is written in the Syslog server.But the file name is Class.Log. I want to give proper log file name.How can I do this?

Comment: You should have a "destination" mode in your Syslog server. There you must declare the name of the .log file.

Comment: Thanks Asier for your reply.But here I have used rsyslog.conf file to configure log file location.Here I have used below configuration.$template RemoteLogs,"/var/log/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log" *
*.*  ?RemoteLogs 
& ~. Folder is created using HOSTNAME , but the log file name is shown as CLASS.log

Comment: Hum..what you're trying seems difficult for the Syslog server, you would need something like Logstash in order to take the exact class name. A simple way to achieve that, if there are not many classes writting, would be creating two (or as much different classes you have) Syslog servers, each one in a different port. Then, in your client side, define two different syslogAppenders (one for port 1 and the other one for port 2).

Comment: Ok. Can you tell me how can i provide PROGRAMMNAME from log4j.properties file or can i use RollingFileAppender to write log in syslog. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What I meant with the second option was to have a STATIC , fixed class name in each SyslogServer. For example, you have classname1 and classname2, each one writting in a different SyslogServer. Each syslog conf creates not a dynamic class name, but a fixed one: 
,"/var/log/%HOSTNAME%/theProgramThatWritesToThisSyslog.log"

Comment: Yes in my case "/theProgramThatWritesToThisSyslog" is equal to CLASS. I could not find that reason.Why all time CLASS.log file is generated in /var/log/%HOSTNAME% directory

Answer (score 1):

I have a working example:

For log4j2 do not use the `Syslog` appender. I had to use `Socket` appender in this way (the `PatternLayout` element simulates the traditional forwarding format for sending data in the wire, see: [smtradfwd.c](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/blob/v8.25.0/tools/smtradfwd.c#L5)):

```
<Configuration status="error" strict="true" monitorInterval="30"
            name="XMLConfigTest" packages="org.apache.logging.log4j.test">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="REMOTE_HOST">some.ip.address</Property>
        <Property name="APP_NAME">rest-server</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Socket name="REMOTE" host="${REMOTE_HOST}" port="514" protocol="TCP">
            <PatternLayout pattern="&lt;128&gt;%d{MMM dd HH:mm:ss} ${hostName} ${APP_NAME}[${sys:PID}]: %-5level %c  %M - %msg%xEx%n" />
        </Socket>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
        <AppenderRef ref="REMOTE"/>
    </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

`<128>` means facility `LOCAL0`. See: [rsyslog.h](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/blob/v8.25.0/runtime/rsyslog.h#L130). In the wire, (and when using traditional forwarding format) every syslog message starts with `<FACILITY_NUMBER>`.

In server side, rsyslog should be configured like this:

```
# provides TCP syslog reception
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514

# Dynamic file
template (name="AppFile" type="string" string="/var/log/remote/%programname%.log")

if ( $fromhost-ip == 'the.remote.ip.address' ) then {

    if ( $programname == 'rest-server' and $syslogfacility-text == 'local0' ) then {
        action(type="omfile" Sync="on" FileCreateMode="0640" DynaFile="AppFile")
        & stop
    }

}
```